# RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding giving error as java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I am using "RSA/None/PKCS1Padding" as :

`Cipher RSACipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/PKCS1Padding");`

This gives me exception as :

`java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/None/PKCS1Padding`

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you please provide more information like, java version, any 3rd party libraries, is it Oracle JDK, Windows or linux etc?

Comment: I also faced this issue. But when I restart the server it is working.

Answer (score 4):

Try `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` instead if you are running in an Oracle or Open JDK. It does not make too much sense to use a block cipher mode of encryption with RSA, but not all algorithm names are logical within the Java SE providers.

The Bouncy Castle Libraries support `"RSA/None/PKCS1Padding"` though. So maybe the code was written for Bouncy or Android.

Comment: It isn't too sensible, but "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" is the name specified by the Java Standard Algorithm Name documentation. It doesn't handle the v. 1.5 versus 2 padding ambiguity either.

Comment: @erickson Even worse, it does not accept data of over keysize - 88 bits either. So what ECB mode would that be?

Comment: Thanks Folks. after reading few more documentation here is what it solved. 
`Cipher RSACipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/PKCS1Padding"); //  this should be PKCS1PADDING` OR just RSA as `Cipher RSACipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");` // default for "RSA/None/PKCS1PADDING"  mentioned here : http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/iaik_jce/current/iaik/pkcs/pkcs1/RSACipher.html

Comment: The Security architecture is case insensitive for algorithm names. Furthermore, you should *always* specify the mode and padding otherwise the provider may choose it's own defaults - and the defaults may differ for each provider. So what you wrote above is very dangerous.

Comment: Thanks, I'll provide provider name.