# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding in jar-file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jar, jce

I do to decrypt and encrypt RSA, I use `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding");` for it, and I added `Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());` and `compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.45'` to gradle-file. So this project to run and work in Intellij Idea,

But if I generate .jar file and to run it, I have:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:540)
```

(generated .jar by ShadowJar task of gradle).

Why my project in Intellij Idea - work! And in .jar-file - does not work?

Comment: Related: [RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding giving error as java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961481/rsa-none-pkcs1padding-giving-error-as-java-security-nosuchalgorithmexception)

Answer (score 5):

`"RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding"` is not something that is available in default security providers of most JDKs. You can use `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` which means the same thing, but uses the ECB name for backwards compatibility.

The BouncyCastle provider does give access to `"RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding"`, but then you need to query it specifically, because adding a provider to the provider list doesn't make it a default provider:

```
Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding", "BC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably built jar file doesn't contain the dependency `org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.45`. 
Please check this out [Using Gradle to build a jar with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies)